# I'm having a difficult time understanding sliders(carousel)

Tags: javascript

today I decided to learn how to make sliders (carousel) , I must point out that I am pretty much new to JavaScript.

First I tried to think how I should code that myself, I had no inspiration or ideas whatsoever. (Just pointless ideas) , so I went to watch youtube in hope of "enlightment" and there were solutions, but a bit too advanced for me to understand.(and long)

After that I googled "how to make sliders" and I found something simpler on w3schools. At first, I was a bit confused, but after a while I started to understand it bit by bit, of course, not totally.

So here comes the question, can someone explain me what each line does and how it affects the others? Or if there is a better and easier method, I would love to hear it.

Here is the javascript file(followed by CSS and HTML), I only modified a few variable names to understand them better and replaced var with let or const:

```js
let index = 1;
showDivs(index);

function plusSlide(value) {
  showDivs(index += value);
}

function showDivs(value) {
  let i;
  let slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if (value > slider.length) {
    index = 1;
  }
  if (value < 1) {
    index = slider.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slider[index - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.sliders {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="plusSlide(-1)">
  <input type="button" value="Forward" onclick="plusSlide(+1)">
  <div class="sliders">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF/?text=image1" width="400" height="200" class="slides">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF00FF/FFFFFF/?text=image2" width="400" height="200" class="slides">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FFFF/FFFFFF/?text=image3" width="400" height="200" class="slides">
  </div>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). w3schools is not a great resource. Too many inconsistencies and poor coding.
There are better tutorials out there. Perhaps follow a beginner tutorial instead of asking us to comment your copypasta? What do you not understand in the code you pasted?

Comment: You have three images with `class="slide"`, but you only show one at once. Broadly, showDivs find all the slides, checks that index is in range (and sets index to the start or end if not), hides all the slides by changing their 'display' style and then shows the one that's selected by index. The way these functions mix up index and the value argument isn't very consistent though.

Comment: If you just want to make a slider (not to learn how to make a slider), there are some greate libraries that may help you.[glidejs.com](https://glidejs.com) looks good enough.

Comment: I'm sorry for the wall of code I posted up there. Next time I will use JSFiddle or something else. And I'm aware that the JS I posted wasn't brilliant. I didn't knew how to do it, so I brought the example I understood the best (at the time).

Comment: @MariusC. it is advisable to include your code in your question; the fact that you included your code in your question is good (and not something to be sorry for). You can make your code runnable by using the "snippet" tool when posting your question (it's the icon at the end at the top), or include a jsfiddle link in addition to  your code. Note that you cannot post jsfiddle links without posting code. Welcome to the stack! :)

Comment: @MariusC. We prefer code here than in JSFiddle unless it is code that does not run here.

Answer (score 1):

This specific approach works like this:
(Explaining in comments)

```
let index = 1; // Initializes index variable to point to the first element
               // of your slide array we'll see later

showDivs(index);

function plusSlide(value) {
  showDivs(index += value);  // This function just increments your index value
                             // and displays the next slide
}

function showDivs(value) {
  let i;
  /*
   You get the array of slides from the dom using the class name slides
  */

  let slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  if (value > slider.length) {  // in case we completed a full circle, we go
                                //from the start again
    index = 1;
  }
  if (value < 1) { // in case we try to go left beyond number 1, we display 
                   // the last one ( to achieve the circular ux experience )
    index = slider.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
    slider[i].style.display = "none";  // Hides every slider
  }
  slider[index - 1].style.display = "block"; // Shows only our index slider
}
```

I don't think this is the best approach. Because every time you want to change slide, every slide from the DOM element is retrieved, and its style is changed. You change the display state of every slide in every click. In my opinion you can
use the `document.getElementsByClassName("slides");` only one time outside
of the function, in a greater scope and thus make your changes.

Also I wouldn't try to iterate through every slide and hide it. I would just
nitialize every slide to have their display equal to "none" and in every showDiv
I would just hide my current index ( before the incremention) and just show next one. Like this:

```
const slider = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");

function showDivs(value) {

  slider[index-1].style.display = "none";  // hides our current slider before 
                                         // the incremention
 
  if (value > slider.length) { 
    index = 1;
  }
  if (value < 1) { 
    index = slider.length;
  }
  
  slider[index - 1].style.display = "block"; // Shows only our index slider
}


.sliders {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it much better now. Basically, every image of my div is set to none, and if my value is higher than my slider index (the number of images) it will start again from the first one. If it's less than the slider index, it will be adjusted to be equal to the slider index, and it will loop exactly like the first if. And afterwards the current slider is shown with display: block. Did I got that right?

Comment: Yes exactly that ;) But as some others users commented, you should explore also more approaches that may be more modern.

Comment: Update: I edited the CSS .sliders and replaced the old JS with the one you gave me, why it's not working? Maybe is something from the HTML?

Comment: Did you copy pasted my JS ? If yes add the functions above also: 

let index = 1; // Initializes index variable to point to the first element
               // of your slide array we'll see later

showDivs(index);

function plusSlide(value) {
  showDivs(index += value);  // This function just increments your index value
                             // and displays the next slide
}

Comment: If you use classes, you can toggle the class using `slider[index-1].classList.toggle("hide")` - that will make it very simple to make transitions